# What kinds of state updates can we defer with `useTransition`?

Tags: reactjs

The React docs show that you can [defer `setState`s by wrapping them in `startTransition` from `useTransition`](https://reactjs.org/docs/concurrent-mode-patterns.html#wrapping-setstate-in-a-transition).

I'm wondering if any one out there knows how this works and what limitations are there.

In particular my questions are:

- can I wrap an update to a context change in `startTransition`?
- can I wrap an update to Redux's `dispatch` in `startTransition`?
- what is the logic for `isPending` of `useTransition` when setStates like redux's `dispatch` are considered?
- [do I need to worry about tearing as defined by Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54891675/what-is-tearing-in-the-context-of-the-react-redux)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> can I wrap an update to a context change in startTransition?

Yes.

> can I wrap an update to Redux's dispatch in startTransition?

No because Redux (currently) has its own state that's not managed by React. If Redux was using React state as the source of truth, it would have been possible.

> what is the logic for isPending of useTransition when setStates like redux's dispatch are considered?

No relation for the reason above.

> do I need to worry about tearing as defined by Mark?

Yes, if you use Concurrent Mode, libraries incompatible with it (like Redux currently) can definitely cause tearing.