# react hooks: What is the disadvantage of directly changing the nested object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

```
import { useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [form, setForm] = useState({
    usename: ``,
    password: ``,
    avatar: { id: 0, url: ``, deep: { id: 0 } },
  });
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>ID:{form.avatar.deep.id}</h1>
      <h2
        onClick={() => {
          form.avatar.deep.id += 1;
          setForm({ ...form });
        }}
      >
        Change-ID
      </h2>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

[codesandbox-online-run](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/dark-frost-gnoe98?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx&selection=%5B%7B%22endColumn%22%3A20%2C%22endLineNumber%22%3A24%2C%22startColumn%22%3A1%2C%22startLineNumber%22%3A1%7D%5D)

I learn reat hooks, people tell me do not change nested object.

We should keep the original state unchanged or use https://github.com/immerjs/immer

But the above code can also update the UI, why ?

What are `form.avatar.deep.id+=1;setForm({ ...form });` disadvantages ?

What are the disadvantages of changing the attributes of the nested object directly?

Comment: One of the issues with that is that it could potentially cause tearing, since the data that React is expecting to not change within a render cycle might change unexpectedly, and as a result a part of the render is done with the old value, while the rest is done with the new value. Here's a topic on tearing specifically on that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54891675/what-is-tearing-in-the-context-of-the-react-redux

Comment: so what you are doing is mutating a state , if you mutate the state it will not cause the re-render

Comment: @ncpa0cpl I understand part of it, can you show `tearing example code` ?

Comment: First of, this kind of tearing can really only happen if you use React concurrent mode as I understand. Then it's pretty much like a race condition. I don't really have any example code for it.

Comment: Also if you're using multiple state values that are both derived from the same initial state array, you can run into issues, see [here](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/updating-arrays-in-state#updating-objects-inside-arrays)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What are form.avatar.deep.id+=1;setForm({ ...form }); disadvantages ?

React is designed with immutable state in mind. This allows doing a very cheap `===` comparison to tell if things have changed. You've copied `form`, and that is enough to get this sample code to work. The old and new form are different objects, so the component rerenders when you set state.

The problem comes if some piece of code cares about a *portion* of the form, not the entire form. If a component wants to check whether `form.avatar` has changed, it will see that no, it has not changed, but in fact it has!

For example, suppose we split out an `Avatar` component as follows:

```
import { memo } from 'react';

function App() {
  const [form, setForm] = useState({
    usename: ``,
    password: ``,
    avatar: { id: 0, url: ``, deep: { id: 0 } },
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <Avatar avatar={form.avatar} />
      <h2
        onClick={() => {
          form.avatar.deep.id += 1;
          setForm({ ...form });
        }}
      >
        Change-ID
      </h2>
    </div>
  );
}

const Avatar = memo(function ({ avatar }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    // Supposed to do some stuff, if avatar has changed
  }, [avatar]);

  return (
    <h1>ID:{avatar.deep.id}</h1>
  )
})
```

In the above code, both `memo` and `useEffect` are broken. `memo` is supposed to render the component if the props changed, and skip rendering if it didn't change. But it will look like `avatar` never changes, and so it will never rerender . Similarly, if the component does render, the use effect will forever think that `avatar` is not changing, and will not rerun the effect.