# Better way to use latest state in useCallback function when used in useMemo without useRef

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-functional-component

UseCase - There is Parent and child component. Child component should not re-render when any unrelated state changes from Parent component.
Here in this example, I have added one button which will increment the count which denotes the unrelated state from the parent.

Child component is not really depends on that state and hence it is not added as dependency for useMemo.
But it is required to use it in one of the callback function.
**I am already aware of useRef hook. I can use it**

Is there any alternative way or any best practice that I can make use of??? Thanks in advance!!!

```
export default function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const onEditCallback = useCallback((name: string) => {
    /* Question - How to use latest parent local
      state varaible without rendering the child component */
    console.log(
      "Question - How to use latest parent local state varaible without rendering the child component????"
    );
    console.log(name, count);
  }, []);

  const renderMyChildComponent = useMemo(() => {
    return (
      <ChildComponent name={"Hello"} onEditButtonClicked={onEditCallback} />
    );
  }, [onEditCallback]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h2>{count}</h2>
      <Button
        variant="primary"
        className="mr-1"
        onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}
      >
        Click me to increment
      </Button>
      {renderMyChildComponent}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Codesandbox url - https://codesandbox.io/s/black-wave-286do7?file=/src/App.tsx:173-1028

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

I will get a disclaimers out of the way – as the React docs take pains to mention: memoisation is an optimisation, and although `useMemo`, `useCallback` etc will generally reuse values, React may still re-compute the initialisers. Situations where you really need to worry about the cost of a child component being re-rendered may not be as common as you think!

Okay, onto the helpful stuff.

React provides the [`memo`](https://react.dev/reference/react/memo) method which allows you to wrap a component so that it skips re-rendering when its props are unchanged. You can use this to get rid of the `renderMyChildComponent` bit:

```js
export const ChildComponent = memo((props: IChildComponentProps) => {
 ...
});
```

You can now use `ChildComponent` directly and it is memoised under the hood:

```js
    <div className="App">
      ...
      <ChildComponent name={"Hello"} onEditButtonClicked={onEditCallback} />
    </div>
```

Comment: A good article to read more on said disclaimers: https://kentcdodds.com/blog/usememo-and-usecallback

Comment: Yeah, but question remain the same :)

Comment: Sorry @sudarshan1933 I missed your question embedded in the markup. The short answer would be no – you either need to pass the latest value explicitly (e.g. a prop), or have a means of accessing the latest value (e.g. a ref). A neat encapsulation of the ref concept is some form of [`useStateWithGetter`](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14543), but ref-based value passing in concurrent mode can lead to [tearing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54891988/21146235), so it should be used carefully.